# Java - Insert Byte Array/ImageIcon directly into HTML

Tags: java, html, image, imageicon

I'm trying to take a byte array directly from the DB and put it into a tooltip that takes HTML. This is for consistency as text needs to be included that will match the other text-only tooltips.

I'm ideally trying to bypass the step of saving the image to a file before loading it into an img src tag. Is there a way to load a byte array (could easily be converted into Image or ImageIcon beforehand) straight into HTML?

Comment: Where are you serving this? With a JSP, servlet or such you can just send the data as pulled from the DB as a response, and put an appropriate URL for requesting it in the 'src' attribute of an img.

Comment: Through a servlet to an applet, loaded as a byte array. This image is then used to make a thumbnail, I'm trying to use the original image (larger) for a fullsize tooltip.

Comment: So just make an image-serving servlet, map it to an appropriate URL and you're golden.

Comment: It just seems wasteful on bandwidth. I have the image loaded in memory anyway, trying to see if there's a way to directly implant it into HTML to avoid having to call it again...

Comment: The bandwidth cost is the same, as you will be loading it every time you load the HTML page in both cases; the only solution to that is to save it to a file so that it gets cached by the browsers.

Comment: It's a good answer, and I'm now just magnifying it instead of using a tooltip, so if you want to write it as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make an image-serving servlet, map it to an appropriate URL and just dump the image data from the database.

Edit: by the way you can have the browser cache the images with this approach, but you to do it manually.

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the bytes to base64 encoding somehow (either on the java side or the html/javascript side). And then you can write something like This:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhUAAPAKIAAAsLav///88PD9WqsYmApmZmZtZfYmdakyH5BAQUAP8ALAA AAABQAA8AAAPbWLrc/jDKSVe4OOvNu/9gqARDSRBHegyGMahqO4R0bQcjIQ8E4BMCQc930JluyGRmdAAcdiigMLVrpTYWy5FKM1IQe+Mp+L4rphz+qIOBAUYeCY4p2tGrJZeH9y79mZsawFoaIRxF3JyiYxuHiMGb5KTkpFvZj4ZbYeCiXaiKBwnxh4fnt9e3ktgZyHhrChinONs3cFAShFF2JhvCZlG5uchYNun5eedRxMAF15XEFRXgZWWdciuM8GCmdSQ84lLQY5R14wDB5Lyon4ubwS7jx9NcV9/j5+g4JADs=" alt="" width="80" height="15" />
```

Note that n this case, even though you save a request to fetch the image, the image itself is not cached for future use.
You may look at this: 
http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/

For a workaround.

Comment: The images I'm trying to load are approx 600x600, may be too large for URI encoding.

Comment: Maximum size is 32kb. If that is not enough, you either resize the image or dump it in a file indeed.

Comment: You could also have an image service that delivers, scale, resize, colorize your images at will frm data from the database.

Comment: @NicolasModrzyk where did you pull that number? AFAIK there is no such limit, the 32kB was just a limit in IE8's poor support.

Comment: @Viruzzo: totally agreed. the 32KB limit is only for IE8.

Comment: Even though he chose the other answer, and that is a good approach.. this one is the correct answer to this specific question.